# How to avoid double zero before comma on HTML input number?

Tags: html, input

I'm trying to accept valid decimals in `<input type="number">` but not accept with double or three zeros before comma.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/xxbrEaz).

Here is my HTML input element:

```
<input id="num" step="0.0001" type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?">
```

This should accept those:
(i.e.)

```
25 

10,25

0,05

0,7
```

But shouldn't accept `00,25` or `000,96`. Because their real values are `0,25` and `0,96`. But they really return with multiple zeros.

How can I avoid these multiple zeros?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `<input type=“text” />` instead of `number`.

Comment: Still accepts 00,25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've prepared something with inspired by [@Marios Nikolaou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614805/marios-nikolaou):

```
$("#num").focusout(function(){
   var inputVal = this.value;
   if(inputVal.indexOf(',') != -1){
      var num = inputVal.split(',');
      this.value = parseInt(num)+","+num[1];
   } else if(inputVal.indexOf('.') != -1){
      var num = inputVal.split('.');
      this.value = parseInt(num)+"."+num[1];
   }
});
```

Comment: input tag with type number doesn't allow `,` so your javascript check is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

When `input` tag lose focus then jquery code will check if there more than one zeros and it will replace it with single one.

```js
 $("#inptNum").focusout(function(){
              var num = this.value.split('.');
              if(num[0] == 0 && num[0].length > 1){
                  this.value = 0+"."+num[1];
              }
          })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input step="0.0001" id="inptNum" type="number" />
```

Comment: And what about 0025.255 value?

Comment: @sundowatch i am glad you are inspired from my answer.I think it's better to update your question with the fix.